# How to convert character based response data with \r\n' to string array using Python

Tags: python

I am using python and reading the data from a stream.

My code shown below.

```
mpc_list = result.response()
print("%r" %mpc_list)
```

Out put i am getting is: `'1\r\n4\r\n10'`

While Out put of print(mpc_list) is shown below:

```
1
4
10
```

Since the array were created with the character objects, so,  when i try to iterate over "mpc_list" array, I got 4 character based elements instead of the three string based objects, which are `1, 4, 1,0`

How can i convert my existing data `'1\r\n4\r\n10'` to array of string like `["1", "4","10"]`?

Comment: Can't you split on `\r\n`?

Comment: Please work through a tutorial on Python string manipulation.  Look for the `split` method.  `mpc_list.split("\r\n")` should do most of your work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try with `split()`:

```
data='1\r\n4\r\n10'
data=data.split('\r\n')
```

Output:

```
data
['1', '4', '10']
```